# replace string in JSON String with variable

Tags: python, json, string, replace

A JSON File is loaded with:

```
with open("samples.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
```

Now I replace the key "22981" with "Automat" in the JSON-String:

```
d = json.loads(json.dumps(data).replace('"22981"','"Automat"'))
```

This works fine. But when I try to do it with variables, it does not work, for example:

```
d = json.loads(json.dumps(data).replace('"{0}"'.format(key1), '"Automat"'))
```

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
d = json.loads(json.dumps(data).replace("{0}".format(key1), "Automat"))
```

You had a single quote together with a double quote.

**Edit**: You should also probably know about f-strings

```
d = json.loads(json.dumps(data).replace(f"{key1}", "Automat"))
```

see [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Answer (score 0):

The below code will replace '22981' key with 'Automat':

```
import json
outfile = open('outfile.json', 'w')
with open("samples.json", "r") as read_file:
for data in  read_file: #To iterate on multiple records in the file(here data is one json record), 
    data = json.loads(data)
    data["Automat"] = data.pop('22981', '')
    outfile.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it with python

```
with open("samples.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
    key="something"
    if data.get(key,None):
      val=data.pop(key)
      data['Automat']=val
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not working with complex nested JSON-Structures...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a workaround. I did the replacement before the json.loads

```
import json
import csv

with open("sensors.json", "r") as read_file:
    sensors = json.load(read_file)
with open ("samples.json", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

for key1 in sensors:
    data = data.replace(key1, sensors[key1]['name'])

data = json.loads(data)
```